# Could we manually renaming class ComposerAutoloaderInitd in custom plugin?

Tags: php

I have been using custom plugin which contains vendor composer folder while pushing to master branch for a site getting error like this fatal error:

> Cannot declare class ComposerAutoloaderInitd87b81449d39bb13ec9d29da767e8f92, because the name is already in use

Comment: That's an autogenerated class name (by Composer). I presume you don't get the error when pushing, but when running the project code. Did you by chance commit your `vendor` folder?